# Set Focus on Open Powerpoint Presentation

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, instance, powerpoint, vb.net-2010

I open a couple of Powerpoint presentations using the same process but multiple instances:

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Core
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
```

and then use this code:

```
Private Sub OpenSlideShow(FullPath As String)
Dim powerpointApp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application()
powerpointApp.Visible = MsoTriState.msoTrue
Dim presentaions = powerpointApp.Presentations
Dim myPresentation = presentaions.Open(FullPath, MsoTriState.msoTrue,            MsoTriState.msoFalse,MsoTriState.msoFalse)
Dim slideShowSettings = myPresentation.SlideShowSettings
slideShowSettings.Run()
End Sub
```

MY PROBLEM:
How do I set focus to any one of the powerpoint presentations when it is open but does not have focus?

I have tried AppActivate but nothing. I have tried SetForegroundWindow but neither seem to work.

Does anyone have a clue?